# django-rest custom url in a ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue adding a custom URL to a ModelViewSet in django-rest-framework. Here's an example of my main urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'post', PostViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
)
```

My modelviewset looks like

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    search_fields = ('created')

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user


    #
    # based on the post type this will decide which serializer to use for the data
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        #
        # default is the Text role serializer
        return PostSerializer
```

That works great for a url like

```
 /api/post/
```

I'm looking to get a set day like

```
/api/post/yyyy/mm/dd/
```

Or should I just use something like

```
/api/post/?year=&month=&day=
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pull the list method out as a separate view:

```
post_list = PostViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
```

Then map this to your date-based lookup URL as you usually would, setting parameters for year, month and day.

In `get_queryset` you can check if these kwargs are set and, if so, filter the queryset.

Comment: This answer helped me a ton! I know it's been a while since you posted it, but do you have any idea if it's possible to register these separately bound (is that the right word?) views with the router, so that they can be seen in the browsable API?

Comment: @dkhaupt You can mark extra actions for routing as per here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing — I'm not sure that gives you what you need. Ultimately you may need to override the template for browsable API and add whatever link you need. (The view itself can be rendered as with any other.)