# Adding more views to a Router or viewset (Django-Rest-Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Essentially, I'm trying to find a good way to attach more views to a Router without creating a custom Router. **What's a good way to accomplish this?**

Here is something sort of equivalent to what I'm trying to accomplish. Variable names have been changed and the example method I want to introduce is extremely simplified for the sake of this question.

Router:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'myobjects', MyObjectViewSet, base_name='myobjects')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

ViewSet

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
""" Provides API Methods to manage MyObjects. """

def list(self, request):
    """ Returns a list of MyObjects. """
    data = get_list_of_myobjects()
    return Response(data)

def retrieve(self, request, pk):
    """ Returns a single MyObject. """
    data = fetch_my_object(pk)
    return Response(data)

def destroy(self, request, pk):
    """ Deletes a single MyObject. """
    fetch_my_object_and_delete(pk)
            return Response()
```

One example of another method type I need to include. (There are many of these):

```
def get_locations(self, request):
    """ Returns a list of location objects somehow related to MyObject """
    locations = calculate_something()
    return Response(locations)
```

The end-result is that the following URL would work correctly and be implemented 'cleanly'.

```
GET example.com/myobjects/123/locations
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [answer given by mariodev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970651/3216056) above is correct, as long as you're only looking to make `GET` requests.

If you want to `POST` to a function you're appending to a ViewSet, you need to use the `action` decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action, link
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    # For GET Requests
    @link()
    def get_locations(self, request):
        """ Returns a list of location objects somehow related to MyObject """
        locations = calculate_something()
        return Response(locations)

    # For POST Requests
    @action()
    def update_location(self, request, pk):
        """ Updates the object identified by the pk """
        location = self.get_object()
        location.field = update_location_field() # your custom code
        location.save()

        # ...create a serializer and return with updated data...
```

Then you would `POST` to a URL formatted like:
`/myobjects/123/update_location/`

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing has more information if you're interested!

Comment: i am trying to upload a file to a custom method. do you know how i can achieve that?

Comment: Is `@action` deprecated - The link suggests methods as arguments to the `@detail_route` decorator.

Comment: '@detail_route' and '@list_route' are marked for deprecation. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations

Answer (score 15):

You can now do this with the list_route and detail_route decorators: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

For example:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
from rest_framework.response import Response
...

class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    ...

    @list_route()
    def locations(self, request):
        queryset = get_locations()
        serializer = LocationSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hi im new to django, what would be the end point for this? thanks!

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab If you have `myobjects-list` and `myobjects-detail`, then this will be `myobjects-locations`.

Answer (score 8):

You define method like you do now, but you need to use the same url as method name and add link decorator, so for

```
/myobjects/123/locations/
```

You add method like this

```
@link(permission_classes=[...])
def locations(self, request, pk=None):
    ...
```

and router will pick it automatically.

Comment: Quick and very precise answer. The only thing I would add is "from rest_framework.decorators import link". Thanks!

Comment: If possible, could you (or anyone) also show me an example of adding a method to the Router which is not 'contained' within my ViewSet?

Comment: @Kurtis does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73651529) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidWolf - I asked this question back in 2013 (almost 10 years ago, haha) and haven't touched DRF in a long time. I'm not sure to be honest :) If I get the opportunity to swing back around, I will let you know and optionally change my selected answer if needed.

Answer (score 3):

From [Routing to extra methods on a ViewSet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-rest-framework/naTNAxw4jws/nue_fhS5vI4J):

> I think you may need to route the method by hand, i.e. The Old-Fashioned Way™.
>
> First pull the method out as a separate view:
>
> ```
>    set_password_view = UserViewSet.as_view({'post': 'set_password'})
> ```
>
> (or such)
>
> Then assign your URL:
>
> ```
>    url(r'^users/username_available/$', set_password_view, name-=...)
> ```
>
> (Or such)

There's a [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18194603/4794).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend a viewset with a view that is or should not directly be written inside your viewset, you can write a “wrapper” action to pass the data through.

For example, with class based views:

```py
from somewhere import YourExternalClassView


class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    # ...

    @action(detail=True)
    def your_action(self, request, pk):
        return YourExternalClassView.as_view()(request, pk=pk)
```

### How does it work?

On class based views, the `as_view` method returns a view function, to which we will pass the data we received from the action. The view will then hand over to process further.

For non-class based view, the views can be called/wrapped directly without `.as_view(...)(...)`.