# How do I use a query parameter for a detail view lookup with django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a `Model` like:

```python
class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.URLField()
    ask = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to use a `ModelViewSet` and look up a single object detail by the `url` field. So I added `lookup_url_kwarg = 'url'` to my `ModelViewSet`:

```python
class BidViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Bid
    serializer_class = BidSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'url'
```

I'm using `DefaultRouter`:

```python
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'bids', views.BidViewSet)
```

but

```
GET /bids/?url={url}
```

doesn't work. The request is always routed to the `list` action. :(

I tried a custom Router:

```python
class BidRouter(routers.SimpleRouter):
    """ Custom Router to allow /bids/?url= for detail view """
    def __init__(self, trailing_slash=True):
        self.routes.append(routers.Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/?url={lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-query-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ))
        super(BidRouter, self).__init__(trailing_slash=trailing_slash)

bid_router = BidRouter()
bid_router.register(r'bids', views.BidViewSet)
```

But it still routes the request into the `list` method.

So, how do I use a query parameter for a detail view lookup?

Comment: Could we see your urls file?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the django-rest-framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views), i think you should use lookup_field instead lookup_url_kwarg. Your bind should be:

```
GET /bids/{url}
```

Comment: I've tried this. But `lookup_field` - like `lookup_url_kwarg` - is only even used in `get_object` during `retrieve` action. The problem is that the request never even makes it to the `retrieve` action. So the problem is "in front" of the `ViewSet` itself. So I'm currently trying a manual route definition like http://stackoverflow.com/a/18196628/571420. I'll report back here.